# Fortran function returning NaN

Tags: fortran

I am trying to find functional value by iteration. Here is my code.

```
   x(3)=g1
   x(4)=1.0
   x(5)=g2
   x(8)=1.0
   x(15)=1.0



    a11=x(10)**2!x(7)**2+x(8)**2+x(9)**2+x(10)**2
    a12=x(7)*x(12)!+x(8)*x(13)+x(9)*x(14)+x(10)*x(15)
    a21=a12
    a22=x(12)**2+x(13)**2+x(14)**2+x(15)**2
    d1=-(x(2)*x(7)+x(3)*x(8)+x(4)*x(9)+x(5)*x(10))
    d2=-(x(2)*x(12)+x(3)*x(13)+x(4)*x(14)+x(5)*x(15))

   det0=a11*a22-a12*a21
   det1=d1*a22-d2*a12
   det2=d2*a11-d1*a21

   dx=det1/det0
   dy=det2/det0

     p1=an+3.
     p2=an+1.
     f(1)=x(2)
     f(2)=x(3)
     f(3)=-p1*x(1)*x(3)+2.*p2*x(2)**2-x(4)
     f(4)=x(5)
     f(5)=-pr*p1*x(1)*x(5)+4.*an*x(2)*x(4)

     do k=1,2
     i(1)=5*k+1
     do j =2,5
      i(j)=i(j-1)+1
     end do
     f(i(1))=x(i(2))
     f(i(2))=x(i(3))
     f(i(3))=-p1*(x(1)*x(i(3))+x(3)*x(i(1)))+4.*p2*x(2)*x(i(2))-x(i(4))
     f(i(4))=x(i(5))
     f(i(5))=-pr*p1*(x(1)*x(i(4))+x(5)*x(i(1)))+4.*an*pr*   (x(2)*x(i(4))+x(4)*x(i(2)))
     end do
```

I am expecting some numerical value but some of variable giving NaN value `a11,a12,a21,a22,det0,det1,det2`. I guess that functions are creating problem.

Comment: Welcome, be sure to take the welcome [tour]. Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions and add a tag for a specific version if the question is version specific (your question likely is not).

Comment: Please give as some bette piece of code. We need the variable declarations, we need to see the `implicit none`, we need to see the start and the end of the function. We need to see the output and the expected output. How do you call the function? Is the function in a module? We *really* need all of this. Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: In addition, consider using compiler flags to trap where the `NaN` is generated. In gfortran, try `-ffpe-trap=invalid,zero`, with ifort, try `-fpe0`. This, coupled with  `-fbacktrace` (ifort: `-traceback`) should help you narrow down the offending expression.

Comment: In addition, consider using compiler flags to trap where the `NaN` is generated. In gfortran, try `-ffpe-trap=invalid,zero`, with ifort, try `-fpe0`. This, coupled with  `-fbacktrace` (ifort: `-traceback`) should help you narrow down the offending expression.

Comment: You have no control over the ways in which a compiler may optimize common factors in these polynomial evaluations.  It could be much more stable if you would write those out explicitly.

Comment: Have you explicity initialised all the elements of the array `x`? Don't expect variables to be automatically initialised with anything sensible.